# Why does Firebase Realtime Database always return { error: 'Permission denied' }? Why isn't authentication working?

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, graphql

I'm trying to set up a Realtime Database. I've used Firebase in the past, specifically web app hosting, but this is my first time with any of the database features. I have a service account set up and I've downloaded the private key JSON. Here's my code for starting a server:

```js
const serviceAccount = require('./../resources/credentials.json');

const firebaseClient = firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});
```

I haven't edited credentials.json at all aside from renaming it such, but that shouldn't be a problem. My issue was still occurring before I renamed it anyway. When the database rules are set up to be completely public and I make a GraphQL query, it runs as expected and I get back the requested information from the database. So I know it's not a problem with my queries either.

When I set the rules to the following:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I expect that *any* authenticated user should be able to access the database. (I'll set it up for only specific users later.) But when I make the query, the only thing that is returned is `{ error: 'Permission denied' }`. I thought passing in the service account credentials was *how* you authenticate, but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

Also, here's part of resolvers.js, the part of my script that actually makes a query to the database:

```js
const baseURL = process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        users: async () => {
            const data = await fetch(`${baseURL}/users.json`);
            const dataJson = await data.json();
            // etc... converting the data json into the format I need
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or is there an easier way to do it? If you need any extra information just leave a comment.

Comment: And "any authenticated user" means users that are either anonymously logged in or logged in with username/password. If you want to log in anonymously and haven't done so, take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added it to the post. I tried request.auth but it said "unknown variable 'request'".

Comment: Yeah. Nevermind. Realtime Database uses a different syntax to Firestore Database. But I think your problem is, you need to log in (anonymously at least)

Comment: @Deffa `request.auth` is Firestore, on Realtime Database it is `auth`.

Comment: @SamHill None of the code in your question can be throwing that error. Please edit the question to show the code that accesses the database, and how you ensure that the user is signed on at that point. If you don't know how you do the latter, I recommend putting `console.log.(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)` right before you access the database, which will likely already show you the problem.

Comment: I'm getting "undefined" for currentUser. That makes sense why it's being denied. But how do I attach a user to it? Shouldn't the service account be the user? Also, I have not yet attached this to the rest of my application. I'm just trying to figure out how to retrieve data from the database using GraphQL without making it completely public. I haven't registered any actual users yet. Am I just doing this completely wrong because none of the tutorials I've found online have mentioned anything further than service account

Comment: The service account is indeed the 'admin' (so never let users get access using this method), but in your code you are not actually using the service account. Take a look here on how you are initializing the database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start
 and then how to query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data